# Pandas multiplying a dataframe column with groupby result

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
cust_sign_month      month         user      country      Charge_volume
2018-01              2018-01        10        DE           100 
2018-01              2018-01        22        DE           200              
2018-01              2018-02        33        IN           100              
2019-01              2019-02        42        IN           200
```

I want a new col "Volume" that will store the result based on the following calculation:

The average of the "Charge_volume" column based on grouping country and month multiplied by the user column

The output should look like this:

```
cust_sign_month      month         user      country      Charge_volume    Volume
2018-01              2018-01        10        DE           100             1500
2018-01              2018-01        22        DE           200             3300 
2018-01              2018-02        33        IN           100             4950 
2019-01              2019-02        42        IN           200             8400
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df['Volume'] = df.groupby(['month','country'])['Charge_volume'].mean()*df['user']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby().transform`:

```
df['Volume'] = df['user'] * df.groupby(['month','country'])['Charge_volume'].transform('mean')
```